# Python: How do you extract a column of data in a csv file if the name of the column has spaces?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

For instance, this code wouldn't work because 'data.apple pies' has a space in between. But this is representative of the column to be selected. So how can I still extract the data from the csv column without altering the name of the column? I could have changed 'apple pies' to 'applepies', and subsequently used data.applepies instead of data.apple pies, but this would be inconvenient if I've to change the names this way for many columns (Or should I just remove all the spaces in the column names?)

```
data = pandas.read_csv('type of foods.csv', names = ['apple pies', 'peach pies'])

applepies = list(data.apple pies)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use subscript to access the column, and if you want to convert it to a list, you should use `Series.tolist()` method instead of `list(...)` . Example -

```
applepies = data['apple pies'].tolist()
```

Please note, the important thing in the answer is to use `data['apple pies']` (subscript) to access the column , with that even `list(data['apple pies'])` would work . But I prefer the `.tolist()` method for converting the series to a list.

---

Demo -

Sample csv -

```
"apple pies"
12
33
33
123
22
```

Code -

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')

In [3]: df['apple pies'].tolist()
Out[3]: [12, 33, 33, 123, 22]
```

Comment: `data = pd.read_csv('type of foods.csv', usecols=["x", "y", "x"])`

Comment: Why do you think so? The OP has clearly said - *this code wouldn't work because 'data.apple pies' has a space in between.* . The issue is with accessing columns with a space in their name.

Comment: The issue is with accessing the column inside pandas, I never said `.read_csv()` never works. Cearly `df.apple pies` does not work. And that is what I am providing a solution to.

Answer (score -2):

This works "with" spaces just fine.

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

csv = r"""apple pies,peach pies,something,else
apple1,peach1,1,2
apple2,peach2,1,2
apple3,peach3,1,2
apple4,peach4,1,2
apple5,peach5,1,2
"""

data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv),
        usecols=["apple pies","peach pies"],
        header=0)

data.columns = ['apple', 'peach']
print list(data.apple)
print data
```

output:

```
['apple1', 'apple2', 'apple3', 'apple4', 'apple5']

     apple      peach
0     apple1     peach1
1     apple2     peach2
2     apple3     peach3
3     apple4     peach4
4     apple5     peach5
```

Comment: The issue is not with reading the csv, its with accessing the column with a space in its name

Comment: And why do you need that? Its completely fine and easy to access columns with space in it in pandas, you can use subscript.

Comment: If you define the columns in the `read_csv` it doenst load unnecessary data into memory, only those specified. Then you can rename the column and access it directly. While your solution is not wrong, it is more of a hack to get things working, this is more robust.

Comment: How is accessing columns via subscript more of a hack? If anything, this solution, which asks you to rename the columns would be more of a hack

Comment: It depends on the use case, but i still disagree.